# why tex4ht ignores fontsize on document title?

Tags: titles, fontsize, tex4ht

When I compile to PDF this latex file

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\title{\footnotesize my title}
\author{me}
\maketitle

This is a test
\end{document}
```

The fontsize of the title changes correctly to `\footnotesize`. But when tex4ht ignores the fontsize change request and always shows the title in very large font. Compiled using `make4ht bug.tex`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I simply wanted to make the title font smaller.

Why does tex4ht ignore font size command in the title? Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround? I tried all other sizes, `\small` etc.. non of them work in tex4ht like in pdf.

```
which tex4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tex4ht
```

Comment: The generated `.css` file has `h2.titleHead{text-align:center;}`. As you should know, changing the appearance of the title should be a job of `\maketitle`, not of formatting instructions in the argument to `\title`. It seems that `tex4ht` enforces this.

Comment: it is so completely wrong to have a size command in the argument to `\title` why would you expect it to be supported by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David and Egreg said, it is not really a good idea to put formatting commands to `\title`. It's contents are used at two places, at place where `\maketitle` was used in the document, and in the `<title>` element.

`<title>` should contain only text, so it could be harmful if any formatting elements   were included here. `tex4ht` tries to clean it, but some rubbish can end here when you use anything but text in your `\title`, resulting in invalid HTML. You can use `\Configure{TITLE+}{alternative title}` in such cases.

You have issue with other `\title` use, in the `\maketitle`. In this place, font processing is disables with `\NoFonts ...`EndNoFonts`. You either should use some CSS to style it according to your wishes:

```
 \Css{h2.titleHead{font-size:0.85em;}}
```

which is preferred way, or you can use alternative configuration for `maketitle`, which doesn't suppress the font processing:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{maketitle}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi \EndP\HCode{<div class="maketitle">}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}
{\IgnorePar\HCode{<div class="title">}\IgnorePar}
{\HCode{</div>}\IgnoreIndent}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the result:

[image]

As I said, I would use the CSS styling.